# tangent bundle on noncommutative manifold

Tags: vector-bundles, noncommutative-geometry, projective-modules

Using the Serre-Swan's theorem, one can do vector bundle theory on noncommutative manifold $(A,H,D)$, by replacing vector bundle by finitely generated projectve module $M$. For the construction of tangent bundle, one can use derivation, but I am not sure how to define derivation on the module. The idea seems to be define derivation on $A$ satisfy Leibniz rule(see [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derivation)). Is this the canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Noncommutative Riemannian (spin) geometry via spectral triples is grounded in an approach to noncommutative differential calculus that privileges the cotangent bundle over the tangent bundle: given a spectral triple $(\mathcal{A},H,D)$, you have an $\mathcal{A}$-bimodule
$$
 \Omega^1_D := \operatorname{Span}\{ a \cdot [D,b] \mid  a,b \in \mathcal{A}\} \subset B(H),
$$
which you interpret as the bimodule of $1$-forms, and a $\ast$-derivation
$$
 \mathrm{d}_D : \mathcal{A} \to \Omega^1_D, \quad \mathrm{d}_D(a) := [D,a],
$$
which you interpret as the exterior derivative from scalar fields to $1$-forms; the pair $(\Omega^1_D,\mathrm{d}_D)$ therefore defines something called a *first-order differential calculus*. It is not automatic that $\Omega^1_D$ is finitely generated projective as a left or right $\mathcal{A}$-module, but hypotheses of this kind have been explored in the literature (see, e.g., [Lord–Rennie–Várilly](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.2196)).

Now, this may begin to sound like the situation in algebraic geometry, where you construct cotangent spaces first and then *define* tangent spaces as their linear duals; certainly, in differential geometry, the tangent bundle is naturally isomorphic to the dual of the cotangent bundle. However, if you now want to define your noncommutative tangent bundle to be something like $\mathfrak{X}_D := \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(\Omega^1_D,\mathcal{A})$, where $\Omega^1_D$ is viewed as a left or right $\mathcal{A}$-module, you run into a basic problem: if $\mathcal{A}$ is noncommutative, there’s no reason why $X \circ \mathrm{d}_D : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{A}$ should ever be a derivation for $X \in \mathfrak{X}_D$. You can solve this by restricting $\mathfrak{X}_D$ to consist of $\ast$-preserving $\mathcal{A}$-bimodule maps $\Omega^1_D \to \mathcal{A}$, but now you’ve just replaced one problem with another: if $\mathcal{A}$ is noncommutative, then this restricted $\mathfrak{X}_D$ will generally be neither a left nor right $\mathcal{A}$-module.

To sum up, then, it’s generally impossible to construct a “noncommutative tangent bundle” $\mathfrak{X}_D$ that simultaneously:

- defines a right or left $\mathcal{A}$-module of left or right $\mathcal{A}$-linear maps $\Omega^1_D \to \mathcal{A}$, and
- yields $\ast$-derivations of $\mathcal{A}$ by composing with $\mathrm{d}_D$.

There is an approach to noncommutative differential calculus that privileges the tangent bundle over the cotangent bundle and works primarily with derivations—the work of Dubois-Violette comes particularly to mind—but for the above reason, it can be difficult to apply in the context of spectral triples.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, I learned a lot in this answer! So instead of tangent bundle, we can actually define some sort of cotangent bundle on spectral triple?

Comment: Exactly. To put things in perspective, there’s a general notion of noncommutative differential calculus based on noncommutative differential forms. Then, a spectral triple gives rise to a canonical noncommutative differential calculus sometimes called the *de Rham calculus* in the literature—this is because you really do recover your usual exterior derivative and differential $1$-forms (up to the inclusion of the cotangent bundle in its complexified Clifford bundle) when your spectral triple is a commutative spectral triple.

Comment: That said, you can’t automatically expect your $\mathcal{A}$-bimodule of de Rham $1$-forms $\Omega^1_D$ to necessarily be finitely-generated projective as a left or right $\mathcal{A}$-module; this is something that may or may not be true for any given example, and it may be a hypothesis you have to impose in certain circumstances.

Comment: One naive question, why do we need to put derivation on $\mathfrak{X}$? If we interpret $d_{D}$ as exterior derivative, as far as I know, exterior derivative do not act on tangent bundle.  In fact I can't see why we need derivation structure on $\mathfrak{X}$. If we do not need derivation on $\mathfrak{X}$, then it seems we can define $\mathfrak{X}$ as some sort of tangent bundle.

Comment: Classically, if $X$ is a vector field and $f$ is a scalar field, the action of $X$ as a $C^\infty(M)$-valued derivation on $f \in C^\infty(M)$ is equal to the the $C^\infty(M)$-valued dual pairing of $X$ with the $1$-form $\mathrm{d}\!f$: $X(f) = (\mathrm{d}\!f,X)$.

Comment: Another thing to think about: if $A$ is a noncommutative algebra, then set of all derivations $A \to A$ will generally be neither a left nor right $A$-module.

Comment: Your fundamental problem really is this, then: you can have a noncommutative tangent bundle over $A$ (which, by the Serre–Swan philosophy, should be a finitely generated projective $A$-module) or you can have noncommutative vector fields on $A$ (which, by direct analogy with the commutative case, should be derivations $A \to A$), but you generally can't have both at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification!

Answer (score 4):

Here are some thoughts which essentially complement Branimir's answer. In many naturally occurring examples, in particular the theory of quantum groups, it is actually more natural to start with a noncommutative cotangent bundle and to then construct the spectral triple from it. More explicitly, start with a pre-$C^*$-algebra $A$ whose noncommutative geometry you are trying to understand.

1. Look for a dga (differential graded algebra) $\Omega^{\bullet}$ for which $A = \Omega^0$.
2. Endow $\Omega^{\bullet}$ with some type of ``Riemannian metric'', which is to say an inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$.
3. Confirm that the differential d of the dga is adjointable $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$. Denote by d$^*$ the adjoint of d.
4. Complete $\Omega^{\bullet}$ to a Hilbert space.
5. Check that the closure of the symmetric operator $D:=$d$+$d$^*$ is a satisfies the axioms of a spectral triple.

I should stress that this is a rough plan of attack, and will only work in situations which are, in some sense, close to the classical situation. For example, $q$-deformed $C^*$-algebras, in particular examples coming from Drinfeld-Jimbo quantum groups.

The prototypical example here is the Podles sphere $\mathcal{O}_q(S^2)$, the degree zero part of a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading on $\mathcal{O}_q(SU_2)$, which $q$-deforms the algebra of algebraic functions of the $2$-sphere. This pre-$C^*$-algebra admits an essentially unique $\mathcal{O}_q(SU_2)$-covariant dga, called the Podles calculus. The calculus carries a $q$-deformation of the Fubini-Study metric, with respect to which $d$ is adjointable, and which gives a spectral triple upon completion of $\Omega^{\bullet}$ and closure of $D = $d$+$d$^*$. The dga constructed from this spectral triple (in the sense Branimir explained above) will coincide with $\Omega^{\bullet}$. This spectral triple was first constructed by Dabrowski and Sitarz (or at least the Dolbeault-Dirac version) and later reconstructed by Majid from a more geometric point of view.

This construction can be extended to a much larger class of examples called quantum flag manifolds . . . but this is very much ongoing work.